# how does the first Activity instance from Activity.Current get created in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, distributed-tracing

if I try to get the activity instance by calling `Activity.Current` in
a console project, I get a null

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var activity = Activity.Current;  // activity is null
        // ...
    }
}
```

and if I call it from a web api project then it is not null

```
[ApiController]
public class PingController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("ping")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PingAsync()
    {
        var activity = Activity.Current;  // activity is NOT null
        // ...
    }  
}
```

so asp.net web api framework must create an `Activity` instance when it recevies the http request, but how does it create it? could you show me the asp.net source code (https://source.dot.net/) that which class create a `Activity` instance and get this instance to `Activity.Current`?

Comment: In asp.net core app the activity is handled by `HostingApplication` https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/HostingApplication.cs . If you are intending to start the activity in a console app , you can start it with `var activity = new Activity("MyActivity"); activity.Start(); ` .